# My beautiful soup can't find the tag in html

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, web-crawler

I'm studying crawling.

```
http://www.wfri.re.kr/client/PublishHp.do?command=view&list_dis_txt=PUB&current_page=1&isu_year=all&list_unq_no=RP00000001847&search_category=&search_keyword=&pub_dt=20170203&topMenuNo=H20000&leftMenuNo=H20100
```

There is a tbody tag on this page.

So,

```
url = http://www.wfri.re.kr/client/PublishHp.do?command=view&list_dis_txt=PUB&current_page=1&isu_year=all&list_unq_no=RP00000001847&search_category=&search_keyword=&pub_dt=20170203&topMenuNo=H20000&leftMenuNo=H20100

source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'lxml')

tdTag = soup.findAll('td',class_='view_cont')
```

But,The result is 0

I thought the JavaScript would run a few seconds later.

So, I wrote that time.sleep(3)

but, the result is also 0

Should I use selenium?

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')))
```

As a result of my research, is it right to write this?

Why is not the tag found?

*** The url address has been modified.

Comment: There isnt any tbody tag in the url mentioned.

Comment: Try `soup.findAll('body')`

Comment: make sure you use the right url

Comment: @ url is http://www.wfri.re.kr/client/PublishHp.do?command=view&list_dis_txt=PUB&current_page=1&isu_year=all&list_unq_no=RP00000001847&search_category=&search_keyword=&pub_dt=20170203&topMenuNo=H20000&leftMenuNo=H20100